# Specifying the height of my jQuery dialog form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery dialog form:

```
$loading.dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    width: '650px',
    height: '75',
    modal: true
});
```

The above works. Below I adjust the height parameter from 75 to '75px'.

```
$loading.dialog({
    create: function () { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide(); },
    closeOnEscape: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    width: '650px',
    height: '75px',
    modal: true
});
```

**It doesn't work anymore. I have a tiny form. How can we explain?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the [height](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-height) option is documented to take either a number or the string `"auto"`:

```
height    Number    Default: 'auto'
```

> The height of the dialog, in pixels. Specifying `'auto'` is also
>   supported to make the dialog adjust based on its content.

As you can see, the `px` suffix is not supported, so your `height` option is ignored.

Comment: @Bronzato, that's a little tricky to explain (see around line 630 in the source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js)). Basically, the `width` option is passed directly to `css()`, which does support an optional `px` suffix. The `height` option, however, is used in a computation (`Math.max(options.height - nonContentHeight, 0)`), and the `px` suffix breaks that computation.

Answer (score 2):

According to [jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-height), `height` must be a number:

> The height of the dialog, in pixels. Specifying 'auto' is also supported to make the dialog adjust based on its content.

Comment: Since Frédéric Hamidi already gave a good answer on that, I should suggest that you always read the docs and avoid [programming by coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence).